# Use specific changes from my stash list

Tags: git, git-stash

Is there a way to use specific changes from my stash list. For example my stash list shows 2 entries `stash@{0}` and `stash@{1}` now I would want to apply {0} to some X branch and {1} to some Y branch. How can I do that? Also can I delete a specific change from the list?

Comment: Switch to the desired branch with `git checkout branchA` and then pop the stash you want to apply with `git stash apply stash@{n}` (this command will leave your stash is the list, use `git stash pop stash@{n}` if you want to remove it from the list.

Comment: @JoëlSalamin Reference the relevant synopsis from the `git-stash` man page and make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply a specific stash to a branch, first switch to the desired branch:

```
git checkout branchA
```

And then apply the desired stash with one of the following commands:

```
git stash apply stash@{n}
```

or

```
git stash pop stash@{n}
```

The `apply` command will leave your stash in the list so you can use it later, if you don't need to keep the stash you can use the `pop` command.

Here you'll find the entire documentation about `git stash` commands: [git-stash Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to run:

```
git stash branch branch-with-stashed-content # stash@{0} implied.
```

Or:

```
git stash branch branch-with-stashed-content stash@{1}
```

TL;DR

Given a Git repository with a root-commit you can run the following commands to give the ones above a try:

```
git init test
cd test
git commit --allow-empty --no-edit --message='My empty root-commit.'
touch foobar
git add foobar
git stash
git stash branch branch-with-stashed-content
```

According to `git help stash`, `branch <branchname> [<stash>]`:

> Creates and checks out a new branch named `<branchname>` starting from
>   the commit at which the `<stash>` was originally created, applies the
>   changes recorded in `<stash>` to the new working tree and index. If that
>   succeeds, and `<stash>` is a reference of the form `stash@{<revision>}`,
>   it then drops the `<stash>`. When no `<stash>` is given, applies the
>   latest one.